# jQuery from 1.5.x to 1.7.x get XML not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had my old code, working flawlessly in jquery 1.5.2, to get and parse an simple XML file

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: "videos.xml",
             dataType: "xml",
             success: function(xml) {
                    console.log(xml);
             }
     });
});
```

for some reason, when I upgraded to 1.7.2 (I had to for other plugins compatibility) this simple function is not working anymore... i really have no idea what can cause that.. any idea?

Comment: The posted code looks perfectly fine. Did you isolate the issue and are you sure that it is the actual piece of code at fault?

Comment: i'll try to isolate the issue later...it's wa sso strange and unprecitable that i'm still speachless ..:(

Comment: the weird thing is when i add error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.log(xhr, status, error);
         } i get an object. maybe my XML is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the issue: it was XML malformed file fault.

for some reason jQuery 1.5.x was more tolerant and didn't threw any error, whereas the newest 1.7+ was stopping form reading the file correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `contentType`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "videos.xml",
      contentType: "application/xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
         console.log(xml);
      }
   });
});
```